# Regular expression issue in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, regex, swift

Hi I want to do a regular expression of Phone validation. It must match with Android Phone matcher class. So, I tried the following expression but it is not working in one scenario.

Expression:
**(\+[0-9]+[\- \.]*)?(\([0-9]+\)[\- \.]*)?([0-9][0-9\- \.]+[0-9])**

It is not working for following number

123d453

But it is working fine in https://regexr.com/ 
By using (+[0-9]+[- .]*)?(([0-9]+)[- .]*)?([0-9][0-9- .]+[0-9])

Please help me.

Code

```
let phone = "123d4"
        let phonereg = "(\\+[0-9]+[\\- \\.]*)?(\\([0-9]+\\)[\\- \\.]*)?([0-9][0-9\\- \\.]+[0-9])"
        if phone.range(of: phonereg, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil{
            print("valid phone")
        }
        else{
            print("Invalid phone")
        }
```

ANSWER:
  Here are the solutions for above issue.

```
 let phone = "123d4"
        let phonereg = "(\\+[0-9]+[\\- \\.]*)?(\\([0-9]+\\)[\\- \\.]*)?([0-9][0-9\\- \\.]+[0-9])"
        let phoneTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", phonereg)
        let result =  phoneTest.evaluate(with: phone)

        if result{
            print("valid phone")
        }
        else{
            print("Invalid phone")
        }
```

Comment: You only allow digits, dashes, brackets and periods, so it can't match the `d`.

Comment: if don't match for that example then is working fine

Comment: Either anchor the regex with `^` and `$` or use within `NSPredicate` with `MATCHES` that requires a full string match.

Comment: Nope, it is taking characters also. im updating my question with code

Comment: Got solution and update answer. Thank you @WiktorStribiżew It works by using NSPredicate